# meaning of "first away league win"

Tags: meaning

> *West Ham 2-3 Leicester City: Rejuvenated Foxes secure **first away league win** in 342 days - 5 things we learned.*

http://www.mirror.co.uk/sport/football/match-reports/west-ham-united-2-3-9643165

Can you explain to me what "first away league win in 342 days" means? The title seems to me to tell that the win over West Ham United was Foxes's first winning match in PL in 342 days, which is of course nonsense.

Comment: 342 days ago was the last time they won a League match when playing ***away*** (i.e - not playing at their own ***home*** ground, where football teams are more likely to win).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
First away league win
```

This is the first time they have won a match in the (Premier) League while playing away from home in the specified time period.

They've won at home in the league and they've won in other competitions.